# Package that allows me to scan QRCode?

Tags: react-native, package, qr-code

Someone know a good package that allows me to scan qrCode inside my app? I don't want to force the user to download a third app to read qrCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have previously used [react-native-qrcode-scanner](https://github.com/moaazsidat/react-native-qrcode-scanner) which I can highly recommend for scanning QR Codes ;)

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend [react-native-camera](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera) for barcode and QR scanning

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [ac-qrcode-rn](https://github.com/MarnoDev/AC-QRCode-RN/blob/master/README.md) which is based on react-native-camera.

It supports both for ios and android and also scans both Qr code and bar code

Scanning interface can be **customized** in many ways which helps the scanning UI look great for user.

Comment: This library is working? Last time i check it was not working maybe because it using older version of react native ?